# Unable to E-mail Multiple BCC Addresses Using Mailjet PHP Wrapper

Tags: php, mailjet

I'm using the Mailjet PHP Wrapper.  https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-simple

For the `to` parameter you can supply an array of e-mail addresses and it works.  But I need to send them as `bcc`.  But when I change `to` to `bcc` nothing sends.

How do I send multiple `bcc`'s???

Their API says `cc` and `bcc` are valid params: http://dev.mailjet.com/guides/send-api-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just replace `to` by `bcc` to send your array of emails by `bcc`.

To have an email sent, you need at least to have one email in `to` and then you'll be able to have your `bcc` array.

`to` is a mandatory field : http://dev.mailjet.com/guides/send-api-guide/

EDIT : I just pushed a modification to handle this case : if there is no `to` but `cc`or `bcc`are not empty, I set `to`to mailjet@example.org.
Tell me if everything is fine now.

Comment: I just verified that, you are correct, thank you.  I'll put myself in the `to` for now.  I would rather see this issue fixed though.  As long as there is at least one e-mail address supplied it shouldn't matter if it's `to`, `cc`, or `bcc`.